# Dockerfile build fails with source-command not found

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build [v8](https://v8.dev/docs/source-code) from source using a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG V8_REPO=https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
ARG ADD_DEPOTTOOLS2PATH='export PATH=/depot_tools:$PATH'

RUN                                         \
apt-get update -y                        && \
apt-get install git -y                   && \
apt-get install vim -y                   && \
apt-get install wget -y                  && \
apt-get install python3 -y               && \
git clone ${V8_REPO}                     && \
echo ${ADD_DEPOTTOOLS2PATH} >> ~/.bashrc && \
source ~/.bashrc
```

For some reason, it fails in `source`-ing `.bashrc`:

```
$ docker build --tag host --file .\Dockerfile.txt .
...
#5 47.17 /bin/sh: 1: source: not found
------
executor failed running [... && source ~/.bashrc]: exit code: 127
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shell which is used by [RUN is /bin/sh](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run). `/bin/sh` does not provide the `source` command.
Try the `.`-command instead of `source`.

Comment: Also worth mentioning here is that the environment gets reset after each `RUN` command, and most Docker paths don't use shell dotfiles, so ending a `RUN` instruction with `... && . ~/.bashrc` probably will do absolutely nothing in practice.